# Drupal 7 - How to disable jQuery UI used by Views Accordion

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, jquery-ui-accordion, drupal-hooks

I'm using the Views Accordion module. I would like to disable the use of jQuery UI that it uses and use pure CSS instead.

I first cloned the module and did the necessary modifications, but then I read that it is not recommended to edit contributed modules, that it is better to create a new module that modifies their functionality, correct?

In the Views Accordion module there is this line in the *views_accordion_style_plugin.inc*:

```
public function pre_render($result) {
     drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

What would I put on my module to disable adding that ui.accordion library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is right, you should never update a contrib module. It is always recommended to create your own module.

Create a new module, with [`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) implementation, and try to unset jquery ui javascript file if it does exist.

Code sample:

```
function MODULE_js_alter(&$js) {

    if(isset($js['misc/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js']))
        unset($js['misc/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js']);
}
```